# Understanding of usage of Maven folder structure

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Once we create maven project, it creates folder structure like following:

[image]

I'm planning to put my Selenium tests in `src/test/java` folder and resources like test data, properties etc in `src/test/resources`. Whatever I'm following here is correct?

If I follow above scenario, there is no use of `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`, would be fine if I remove them from folder?

Or let me know how can I use that folder structure in better way for Selenium tests.

There is one more folder `src` in the project. What is that for? How can I make use of that folder?

Comment: I don't know about Selenium but if you don't have any use for ```src/main/java``` and ```src/main/resources``` you can remove those folders.

Comment: The src folder you're seeing is the same as the one in the 4 source directories. It's listed there so that you can open it and see files that are not part of any of the 4 source subfolders

Answer (score 0):

In your project there is only one src folder, you can see it if you go to the folder directly with the browser, without using Eclipse.

What you see that structure/view is:

- The source folders (Source folders are a way to cut down on a
  project's indexing scope. You can mark the folders that are part of
  your day to day work or part of a subsystem that you work on. All
  files inside source folders will be indexed and are, thus,
  searchable. Note that any files pulled in by a file inside a source
  folder will also be indexed.)
- Dependencies: JRE and Maven dependencies
- The physical folder of src: Inside it there is the same content of the source folders, but
  with folder structure, because there are same things.
- Binaries and pom.xml

About the selenium case, it depends. You can create a Selenium folder in your main project into src/test/java, and put the tests there (you do not need another project) or put it another project as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Maven would help you to build a standard project directory structure for the type of "archetype" you have chosen. So the kind of project you created looks like a generic java project which will have a source code folder and resources folder. Corresponding to that, it would also have provision for writing unit tests during the development phase. So the folders containing "test" would hold those unit tests in form of java classes and required resources.
In your case, since you don't need the java part of the project, you could leave them empty rather than removing them. May be in future you would need to "stub" some functionality and you would use those folders.

You can explore the list of archetypes at below given link and check if any archetype exist for Simply test projects.

[http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Archetypes+List][1]